# How to store images and refere to it for my iOS interface?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using XCode 6.

Let's say I have a Food model containing a `(UIImage *)image` property. I would like to display all my foods displaying images for my interface.
I have already the pictures for the foods (they are not in the Photo Library of the device but on my computer).

1) Where to put these image files (beet.png, banana.png etc... for example) in Xcode ? (is there a dedicated folder ?)

2) How to refere to this image file ? Example in my Food class, `self.image = ?`

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just drag and drop image files to your project while xcode is open.

make sure you use copy items if needed option, it is less hassle.

once you clikc finish for your files, you will see your files on bundle.

[image]

then all you need to do is call
`[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageInBundle.png"];`
`imageNamed:` will search your main bundle

or long way

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"YourBundle" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
NSString *imagePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"imageInBundle" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you can create new group inside your project in XCode and drag images to it. Check in build phases, in Copy Bundle Resources to make sure they'll be copyed in final app. 2) you refer image using imageWithName. You can use UIImageView for easier management and set this image your imageWithName. Otherwise you can implement directly images in your xib. Anyway how do you want to use images? In a table, in a collection, in a detail view? Depends on you how you want to display them and how you manage to make things work.